# how to push the code to remote code repository server?

Tags: git, ssh, vpn

bitconnect server is running in remote server where we dont have direct access. we should connect the jump server through VPN and check-in the code in bitconnect server through SSH.

At this situation, how to checkIn the code directly to remote code repository from eclipse?

Comment: Do you ssh to the jump server or can you ssh directly to the bitconnect server?

Comment: i cannot connect the bitconnect server directly from my local system. I should connect SSH to jump server only.

Comment: See if something at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+jump+server helps.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is to run git through an ssh tunnel.

```
ssh -L3456:bitconnect.server.ip:22 user@jump.server.ip
telnet localhost 3456
git clone ssh://git@localhost:3456/example.git
```

The above commands works as follows:

1. This creates an ssh connection to jumpserver-ip and sets up a TCP
   tunnel between your localhost port 3456 through the jumpserver-ip
   and to port 22 on the bitconnect-server. You can replace 3456 with
   another port number.
2. If you receive a message from your SSH server, the connection works!
3. Clone the repo through the tunnel. Then setup a pushurl through the
   tunnel too.

Note: You will need to setup that tunnel everytime you want to do a git transaction with the bitconnect server.